# docment.body.innerHTML not working with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have an html file with source code

```
<html>
<head><Title>Hello!!</Title>
<script>

window.onload=function(){var bodyElement = document.body;
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
document.body.innerHTML ='<iframe srcdoc='+document.body.innerHTML+'></iframe>' ;

}
</script>

</head>
<body><h1>Hello World
</h1></body>

<html>
```

in console it is showing

```
<h1>Hello World
</h1>
```

but in browser it is showing only a rectangular box nothing in it(expecting

## Hello World

in it ) why i am getting an empty box and how to put document.body into a iframe??

Comment: Does your browser support the `srcdoc` attribute?

Comment: i am using chrome 24.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed the quotes:

```
document.body.innerHTML ='<iframe srcdoc="'+document.body.innerHTML+'"></iframe>' ;
```